# Categorical time series forecast accuracy

Tags: time-series, forecasting, model-evaluation, accuracy

This is a general question. Can anybody please point me in the direction of how I can compare the forecasts of a 3 level categorical time series by three competing models? I would like to compare the forecasts to the ground truth of what actually occurred. The forecasts are 1 to 6 days ahead. Is it correct to analyse each day ahead separately? We have forecasts for 4 years. Should they be analysed separately to allow for variation in each year or can the years be used more wholistically? The prediction accuracy for each each model for each day is assessed with the Gerrity score.

I am happy to provide more info if required. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I have not seen this addressed in the time series literature, where commonly you predict interval variables like spending. You can calculate the percent of time you are right for each model(you predict level 1 and it is level 1) for one period ahead, 2 etc. Personally I have little confidence in predicting beyond a year although it depends of course on your data.